# on change event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

1) The code(Change Event) that is not working is:

```
$(document).on('change','select[name="id"]',function(){
    alert('Not Working');
});
```

2) The code(Change Event) that is working is:

```
$(document).on('change',$('select[name="id"]'),function(){
    alert('Working');
    // Here $(this).val() not working for get value.I want to use $('select[name="id"]').val()
});
```

Doubts:

a) Why Is First change event not working?

b) Second change Event is Working, But $(this).val() is not working.

Can you please explain the difference between above 2 functions?

Comment: I'm surprised the second one works; it's certainly not documented to. The first should. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: First, please share a snippet with working code. The signature is correct. Next, is far better to trigger onChange directly on select instead of document.

Comment: Please share your markup as well here specially select element on which you trying trigger change event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to handle `select` element change:

```
$('select[name="id"]').on('change',function(){
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

For **dynamically created elements** use:

```
$(document).on('change','select[name="id"]',function(e){
    alert($(e.target).val());
});
```

As you see, in that case `e.target.val()` should be used ( *e.target wrapped into `$()` in order to get it as a jquery object* )

Comment: And what if he wants to delegate the event handler to dynamically created elements?

Comment: @empiric See my updated answer ^

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your first example doesn't work as I think it should, however the second example will have `this` scoped to `document` instead of the select.

The following will scope `this` to the select.

```
$('select[name="id"]').on('change', function (){
    $(this).val()
});
```